# Catching IntegrityError vs filtering before object creation?

Tags: python, django

I have a development task. And at some point of this task, I need to create DB objects with a function which takes multiple json objects returning from third-party client request. I am for looping through json objects and calling `_create_db_object` method to create them one-by-one.

Sample model:

```py
class MyObject(models.Model):
   some_unique_field = models.CharField(unique=True)
   ...
   ...
```

The function I use to create objects in DB:

```py
def _create_db_object(dict_: dict[str, str]) -> None:
    try:
        return MyObject.objects.create(...)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        continue
```

My question is: "Would it be better if I used something like this instead of try except?"

```py
def _create_db_object(dict_: dict[str, str]) -> None:
    if MyObject.objects.filter(some_unique_field=dict_["unique_field"]):
        continue

    return MyObject.objects.create(...)
```

Which function would be better and why?

Comment: I generally use django's get_or_create() method for preventing duplicates as it is simple than using filter().exists(). 
However, even get_or_create may raise integrity error during race conditions.
checkout this thread https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24009.

Comment: You might also be interested in using [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) with `ignore_conflicts=True`